# Handling IE and that it doesn't handle fileSize, etc

Tags: json, browser, error-handling, fine-uploader

I'm using v3.9 UI with jQuery wrapper:

Now that I've solved my 'Maximum Request Length Exceeded' error within IE9 (from here:
[FineUploader Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252538/fineuploader-error-handling)
).  All my FineUploader code is within this other link, and didn't think I needed to post it again.

I'm now looking for a better way to let IE users know when they've attempted to upload a file that's too large (Chrome, FF users get the too large file alert, so this isn't a problem).  I don't think I need to mess with the 'messages' option as these are working as they should for all the other browsers.  It's IE that's not working as it should!  IE users will get all the way up to the server with the file they've selected. For handling uploading a file that exceeds the fileSize property, I have code on my server side to checks content length > 'n' and if so then return JSON success = false.  See below:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileWrapper qqfile, int surveyInstanceId, int surveyItemResultId, int itemId, int loopingIndex)
    {           
            bool isValid = false;

            // file is too big, throw error.
            if (qqfile.ContentLength > (1024*1024*2.5))
            {
                return CreateJsonResult(false);                    
            }

       More Code here if the file is 'good'
    }

  private JsonResult CreateJsonResult(bool isSuccess)
    {
        var json = new JsonResult();
        json.ContentType = "text/plain";
        json.Data = new { success = isSuccess };
        return json;
    }
```

This short circuits an invalid file upload based on size.  Great, but can I return more than just success=false and have this additional JSON value used by FineUploader to display a more useful message to the user?  Currently all that shows is 'Upload Failed'.  How do I reference the specific html element for that invalid file, so I can add a more descriptive error?

Also, I do have the .on('error') method, but I'm not sure how to trigger this.  This would be a logic place to look, as the file upload size issue IS an error.  Help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using the Content-Length of the request to enforce file size restrictions is not a good idea.  All upload requests sent by Fine Uploader, by default, are multipart encoded.  The Content-Length for multipart encoded requests is the size of the ENTIRE request, not just the file.
2. In a comment to your answer for your last question, I pointed to a specific section of the documentation that allows you to control the failure text that appears next to a file in Fine Uploader UI mode.  All you have to do is set the `mode` property of the `failedUploadTextDisplay` option to "custom".  Server-side, return the error message text you would like to appear next to the failed file in an "error" property of your JSON response.  See the bottom of the ["handling errors" documentation section](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/handling-errors.html) for more details.

**UPDATE**

It looks like you are using the `ContentLength` property of the `HttpPostedFileWrapper` which returns the size of the uploaded file.  This was a bit confusing for me at first, since Content Length generally refers to the size of a request.  The name choice for this property was a poor one on Microsoft's part, IMHO.  So, you can disregard #1 in my answer.