# Fineuploader Lag with file selection on iPhone iOS6 & iOS7

Tags: ios, lag, fine-uploader

I'm running v3.9 using the UI jQuery wrapper design and all is working well for desktop and Android.  iPhone iOS' 6 and 7 are having serious lag between clicking on the file selection button and having it actually become visible.  From actual users (and my own testing with the BrowserStack emulator site) it's taking 3+ minutes or so for file selection to appear, with no indication that anything is happening.  What's up with this?

My code can be seen here in a previous post: ['Fineuploader Error Handling'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252538/fineuploader-error-handling/19254281#19254281) :

[image]

For my own personal Android device using Chrome and Opera Mobile everything works great, and the control is responsive.  Has anyone run into the lag issue I'm talking about on newer iOS'?  Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with iOS.  I have raised the issue with Apple in the past, but have not even received an acknowledgement.  The issue is not related to Fine Uploader and can be reproduced with a simple file input element on iOS devices.  This affects iOS6+.  You can read more about this in [issue #857](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/857) in the Fine Uploader Github repo.

Comment: Well, $hit.  I appreciate the fast response, but this is bad bad bad bad.

Comment: You must be selecting a _lot_ of files.  While I've seen a noticeable lag on iOS (10-20 seconds) I've never seen 3+ minutes.  Anyway, while I'm a big fan of Apple products in general, their browsers are pretty awful for the most part.  They seem to ignore [established standards](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/396) and fail to address bugs that have existed for some time.  Not to mention the fact that the dev tools for Safari are a joke.  Not sure there is much that can be done if Apple refuses to make their browsers a priority.

Comment: This is before the user can even select files.  They're just clicking the FineUploader 'select files' button to begin the selection process.  There's a crazy long lag before this window appears.  Once it pops up, they're typically only selecting one or two files.

Comment: There there is something else going on either on the device you are using, or perhaps with some other js library.  I've never seen that.  Invoking the select files dialog is trivial.  In fact, Fine Uploader isn't even involved.  The browser will directly target the file input element, which results in the select files dialog.  If your click results in a 3+ minute wait before the dialog appears, I'd spend some time tearing apart your web app to figure out what is causing this.

Comment: Okay, but here's some more info for you.  There are 3 people here that have iPhones, and all with the same lag issue.  iP4 and iP5S are both running 7.0.2.  One 5S is brand new with only 2 pictures on it...  Looking into the web app, thanks.